# Thread with while (true) loop exits somehow

Tags: c#, multithreading, while-loop

I have a thread that is supposed to run continuously in my program and parse incoming serial data from a collection of sensors.

```
//initialized as a global variable
System.Threading.Thread processThread = new System.Threading.Thread(ProcessSerialData);

//this gets called when you press the start button
processThread.Start(); 

private void ProcessSerialData()
{
    while (true)
    {
        //do a whole bunch of parsing stuff
    }
    int howDidYouGetHere = 0;
}
```

How is it possible that my program is reaching the "int howDidYouGetHere = 0" line??

Full code can be found here:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// ProcessSerialData thread will be used to continue testing the connection to the controller,
    /// process messages in the incoming message queue (actually a linked list), 
    /// and sends new messages for updated data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void ProcessSerialData()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            UpdateAhTextbox(test.ampHoursOut.ToString());

            if (!relayBoard.OpenConn())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection to controller has been lost.");
                testInterrupted = "Lost connection. Time = " + test.duration;
                UpdateStatusText(false);
                ShutErDown();
            }

            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            if (incomingData.Count > 0)
            {
                string dataLine = "";
                try
                {
                    dataLine = incomingData.First();
                    UpdateParsedDataTextbox(dataLine + "\r\n");
                }
                catch (System.InvalidOperationException emai)
                {
                    break; //data hasn't come in yet, it will by the time this runs next.
                }

                incomingData.RemoveFirst();

                if (dataLine.Contains("GET")) // some sensor values (analog/temp/digital) has come in
                {
                    if (dataLine.Contains("GETANALOG")) // an analog value has come in
                    {
                        int index = dataLine.IndexOf("CH");
                        int pin = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(dataLine[index + 2]);

                        double value = 0;
                        int dataLineLength = dataLine.Length;
                        if (dataLineLength > 13) // value is appended to end of line
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                value = Convert.ToDouble(dataLine.Substring(13));
                            }
                            catch // can't convert to double
                            {
                                int index2 = dataLine.IndexOf("CH", 3);
                                if (index2 != -1) // there happen to be two sets of commands stuck together into one
                                {
                                    string secondHalf = dataLine.Substring(index2);
                                    incomingData.AddFirst(secondHalf);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else // value is on the next line
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                value = Convert.ToDouble(incomingData.First());
                                incomingData.RemoveFirst();
                            }
                            catch // can't convert to double
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Error occured: " + dataLine);
                            }
                        }
                        switch (pin)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                ReadVoltage(value);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                ReadAmperage(value);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (dataLine.Contains("GETTEMP")) // received reply with temperature data
                    {
                        int index = dataLine.IndexOf("CH");
                        int pin = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(dataLine[index + 2]); // using index of CH, retrieve which pin this message is coming from

                        double value = 0;
                        int dataLineLength = dataLine.Length;
                        if (dataLineLength > 11) // value is appended to end of line
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                value = Convert.ToDouble(dataLine.Substring(11));
                            }
                            catch // can't convert to double
                            {
                                int index2 = dataLine.IndexOf("CH", 3);
                                if (index2 != -1) // there happen to be two sets of commands stuck together into one
                                {
                                    string secondHalf = dataLine.Substring(index2);
                                    incomingData.AddFirst(secondHalf);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else // value is on the next line
                        {
                            value = Convert.ToDouble(incomingData.First());
                            incomingData.RemoveFirst();
                        }
                        ReadTemperature(pin, value);
                    }
                    else // must be CH3.GET
                    {
                        int index = dataLine.IndexOf("CH");
                        int pin = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(dataLine[index + 2]); // using index of CH, retrieve which pin this message is coming from

                        if (pin == 3) // only care if it's pin 3 (BMS), otherwise it's a mistake
                        {
                            double value = 0;
                            int dataLineLength = dataLine.Length;
                            if (dataLineLength > 7) // value is appended to end of line
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    value = Convert.ToDouble(dataLine.Substring(7));
                                }
                                catch // can't convert to double
                                {
                                    int index2 = dataLine.IndexOf("CH", 3);
                                    if (index2 != -1) // there happen to be two sets of commands stuck together into one
                                    {
                                        string secondHalf = dataLine.Substring(index2);
                                        incomingData.AddFirst(secondHalf);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else // value is on the next line
                            {
                                value = Convert.ToDouble(incomingData.First());
                                incomingData.RemoveFirst();
                            }
                            ReadBMS(value);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (dataLine.Contains("REL")) // received reply about relay turning on or off.
                {
                    if (dataLine.Contains("RELS")) // all relays turning on/off
                    {
                        if (dataLine.Contains("ON"))
                        {
                            for (int pin = 1; pin <= 4; pin++)
                            {
                                test.contactors[pin] = true;
                            }
                        }
                        else // "OFF"
                        {
                            for (int pin = 1; pin <= 4; pin++)
                            {
                                test.contactors[pin] = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else // single relay is turning on/off
                    {
                        int index = dataLine.IndexOf("REL");
                        int pin = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(dataLine[index + 3]);

                        if (dataLine.Contains("ON"))
                        {
                            test.contactors[pin] = true;
                        }
                        else if (dataLine.Contains("OFF"))
                        {
                            test.contactors[pin] = false;
                        }
                        else if (dataLine.Contains("GET"))
                        {
                            if (Convert.ToInt32(incomingData.First()) == 1)
                                test.contactors[pin] = true;
                            else
                                test.contactors[pin] = false;
                            incomingData.RemoveFirst();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            // we only want more data if we're done processing the current data, otherwise we're stuck with too much and processing is heavily delayed.
            if (isTestRunning && incomingData.Count < 3)
            {
                //read & output v, a, bms state
                sendToController("CH1.GETANALOG"); // get voltage
                sendToController("CH2.GETANALOG"); // get amperage
                sendToController("CH3.GET"); // get BMS state

                //read & output temperature
                sendToController("CH4.GETTEMP"); // get temperature
                sendToController("CH5.GETTEMP");

                string lines = "Ah Out: " + test.ampHoursOut + ", Voltage: " + test.voltage +
                    ", Amperage: " + test.amperage + ", Cell Temperature: " + test.tempBattery +
                    ", Load Temperature: " + test.tempLoad;
                WriteToLog(lines);
            }
        }
        int howDidYouGetHere = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Instead of break, try a continue.

Comment: My try-catch doesn't catch the exception for some reason, so I'll need to find a more overarching fix for this. Reading about locks now, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `break` (ignoring those inside the nested `switch`) breaks out of the `while` loop.

Comment: Perhaps the OP intended to use continue instead.

Comment: The break does not break out of the while loop. It's proper syntax for switch statements (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx). 

My program will run for up to 40 seconds and then only exit the while loop. That break statement gets hit up to 100 times in that time.

Comment: The break in your `catch` block.

Comment: @jules0075 As I said in my answer, those `break` operations nested in the `switch` aren't going to cause this.  The one that isn't in a `switch`, is.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you have tried to update your UI using `UpdateParsedDataTextbox` This will cause `InvalidOperationException`(then breaks the while loop) because you tries to access the UI control from thread that doesn't own the control.

Comment: An exception would result in the loop being exited, but it wouldn't result in code directly after the end of the loop being run.  The exception would end up propogating up past any such code until it hit an appropriate `catch` block.

Comment: @Servy That also can take a place.